# Needing FTP Software with editing and hides system files?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, ms-office, ftp

I am looking for FTP Client software for Mac that

- Doesn't show hidden system files on the server
- Can edit files using MS Office and then save them back onto the FTP site automatically without the user having to download the file, edit the local copy and then upload the local copy and replace the remote copy.

I have tried various FTP software and only a handful don't show hidden system files on the server which is good, and some automatically open files when they are double clicked using the correct software (Word, Excel etc..) but then when you save it doesn't update the remote copy.

Comment: Can you list the applications you already tried out and which are not suitable for your situation?

Comment: You don't say what OS the server you are connecting to is, which could influence answers as some clients may understand Windows folder hierarchy but not Linux, or Mac, and vice versa etc etc.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that [Transmit](https://panic.com/transmit/) from Panic Software will meet all of your needs.

There is a menu option that toggles the visibility of dot (.*) files. View menu (Hide/Show) Invisible Files.

To edit a remote file in Word, right click on the remote file and select "Open With..." and select Word from the context menu to edit the file. Edit and Save the file within Word and the file will be uploaded as soon as the save completes. There is nothing else to set up.

I usually use this method with BBEdit and Text files, but I tested and it works with Word files.

Answer (score 1):

1. Within [ForkLift](http://binarynights.com/forklift/support) (a paid application), you can use **View > Hide Invisible Items** (<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) to hide hidden files on the FTP server.
2. You could use the [Disklet feature in ForkLift](http://binarynights.com/forklift/support) to use remote locations like they were local locations (so you can open files and save them within an app without downloading, saving locally and uploading):

   > **Q: What are Disklets and how do I use them?**
   >
   > A: Disklets allow you mount any of your remote connections, making them appear to your Mac as local drives. Once mounted you can directly access your files on the server from any app.
   >
   > To mount a remote connection as a Disklet right click on a remote favorite in the favorites manager or in the sidebar and choose Mount as Disk.

---

Other applications that allow you to edit remote files directly without an explicit "download, edit, save locally and upload" workflow are:

1. [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) (free and open source)
2. [Flow](http://fivedetails.com/flow/) (paid app)